# Unable to execute maven command via script using java

Tags: java, shell, maven

I am unable to execute maven command via script using java. The maven command is suppose a create an archetype folder which is not being created.

This is what the java code looks like :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/log/script.sh");
pb.directory(new File("/log"));
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();        
IOUtils.copy(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
```

This is what **script.sh** looks like

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=my.archetype -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  -DgroupId=my.groupid -DartifactId=artifact -Dpackage=my.groupid.artifact -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeRepository=<link-to-repo>
ls
```

I can see in the output of the **ls** command that the folder that was supposed to be created by the maven command is not getting created, whereas, when I try running the script from the terminal, it gets created. I have giving the folder 777 permission. Can someone let me know what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you seeing any error ?

Comment: Nope. No error on the console atleast

Comment: Is that the complete code ? Where are you calling the start method on the pb object ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had missed it while copy pasting

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of observations:

1. The stream returned by `getInputStream()` is the *standard output* stream for the child process.  Error messages are *typically* written to *standard error*.  Try reading `getErrorStream()` instead / as well.
2. I'm not sure if it is even possible to read a `Process` object's standard output / error after the call to `waitFor()` has returned.  It could give you nothing at all, or a truncated stream.  In the worst case, it could deadlock.  (The external process gets stuck because its output / error pipe is blocked ... 'cos nothing is reading it.  Therefore it canbot exit.  Therefore the Java `waitFor()` call cannot return.  But the Java side only reads from the pipe *after* `waitFor()` returns.)

Fixes:

1. Do the `IOUtils.copy` in a separate thread, and start that thread before you call `p.waitFor`.
2. Read both streams ... or use redirection to combine them into one stream.
3. Alternatively, redirect the output to a file and look at it external to Java.

There is a lot of material in the ProcessBuilder on how to implement redirection.  Alternatively, do it in the shell script.

Comment: Using getErrorStream() I was able to find out the problem in the script. I had to set the mvn path explicitly when I was executing the script via Java.